# Style changes for a moment when parameters change

Tags: manipulate, style

I've been looking for a solution to this problem for other applications too, for some time, but haven't come up with a solution that does not involve `Animate` or similar (and it never works).

Take this example:
plot a function (say `f=a/x`) for different `a`. The y-axis plot range is based off of `a/1` but there are say, 3, possible plot ranges:

```
range=Which[f<2,2,f<5,5,f<10,10]
```

for `1<=a<=10`.
Each time `range` changes as `a` changes (with `Manipulate` slider), the `FrameStyle` for the changing y-axis should flash red then return back to black.

Every time I've encountered this issue I was using `Manipulate` (and need to find a solution to this while still using `Manipulate`).

Here's what I want to show but WITHOUT having to use the method I used to creat this, which was:

```
Which[
  f[1] < 1.9, Black,
  1.9 <= f[1] <= 2.1, Red,
  2.1 < f[1] < 4.9, Black,
  4.9 <= f[1] <= 5.1, Red,
  5.1 < f[1] < 9.9, Black,
  9.9 <= f[1] <= 10, Red
  ]
```

for the `FrameStyle`. Here's what it did, for clarification:

[image]

Comment: Can you show the full code you used to generate the `Manipulate` output you showed in the screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the `Which` by dynamically setting `PlotRange` and `FrameStyle` as a function of `f`

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10},
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, Max[axisStep Quotient[f[1], axisStep], 2]}},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameStyle -> 
   {With[{z = Mod[f[1], axisStep]},
     If[flashRange > z \[Or] z > axisStep - flashRange, 
      Directive[Thick, Red], Automatic]],
    Automatic}
  ],
 {{a, 1}, 1, 12},
 Initialization :> (axisStep = 5; flashRange = 0.3; f[x_] := a/x),
 TrackedSymbols :> {a}]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that works.

I am quite certain that there are more efficient ways to accomplish this but at least the code is fairly easy to follow.

I tried wrapping the right hand side of `AxesStyle` in `Dynamic` but it didn't work so I ended up wrapping the whole plot in `Dynamic`.

The `Manipulate` variables with `ControlType->None` is one way of introducing dynamic variables (one could also use `DynamicModule`).

When you get a working version you will undoubtedly want to reduce the time for the `Pause` and may want to get rid of the `Thick` when the y-axis is Red.

One of the workhorses is the list of functions that follow the `Dyanmic[Plot,...`.

`Dynamic` can take an expression and zero, one, two or three functions. For the case with three functions the first one applies at the start, the second during and the last at the end.

```
Manipulate[

 ytop = Which[
   a < 2, 2,
   a < 5, 5,
   a >= 5, 10
   ];

 If[ytop != ytopSaved,
  ytopSaved = ytop;
  scaleChanged = True
  ];

 Dynamic[
  Plot[
   a/x, {x, 0, 10},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, ytop}},
   AxesStyle ->
    {
     Black,
     ydirective
     }
   ],
  {ydirective = If[scaleChanged,
     Directive[Thick, Red], Black
     ],
   If[scaleChanged, Pause[1]],
   scaleChanged = False;
   ydirective == Black}
  ],

 (* Manipulate variables *)

 {{ydirective, Black}, ControlType -> None},
 {{ytop, 2}, ControlType -> None},
 {{ytopSaved, 2}, ControlType -> None},
 {{scaleChanged, False}, ControlType -> None},
 {{a, 1}, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Open"}

 ]
```

The top figure shows the case where the y axis scale has not changed, and the bottom figure shows the case during the change of the y axis scale.

[image: Mathematica graphics]